# Swagger doctrine/zircote bearer Authorization code

Tags: php, doctrine, swagger, jwt, bearer-token

i'm trying to use swagger zircote to create the swagger ui json.
for my application i use JWT and i need the following swagger code in my json:

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "Bearer": {
      "in": "header",
      "type": "accessToken",
      "name": "Authorization"
    }
},
```

But i dont know how i create that code with swaggers zircote. I've tried the following code:

```
 * @SWG\Swagger(
 *     schemes={"https"},
 *     @SWG\SecurityDefinitions(
 *         bearer={
 *             type="apiKey",
 *             name="Authorization",
 *             in="header"
 *         }
 *     ),
```

but this results in the following error:

> The annotation "@Swagger\Annotations\SecurityDefinitions" in
>   .\index.php on line 2 does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

Can someone help me, i cant find any good documentation about this, maybe its to specific, but i hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Issued this also on the github... https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/366

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@SWG\SecurityScheme` instead of `@SWG\SecurityDefinitions`.

```
 * @SWG\Swagger(
 *     schemes={"https"},
 *     @SWG\SecurityScheme(
 *         securityDefinition="Bearer",
 *         type="apiKey",
 *         name="Authorization",
 *         in="header"
 *     ),
```

A list of available annotations can be found list in [vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Annotations](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/tree/master/src/Annotations)

Comment: Thanks! especially the list of annotations 2, i never expected it there!

Comment: sorry i have to put this here, but i cant find a way to mention you in my new post, but maybe do you have an answer to this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527952/how-to-add-correctly-a-parameter-without-errors-in-swagger-zircote-doctrine

Comment: Just tag the question with `swagger-php` and i'll receive a notification.

Comment: So how do I actually use this SecurityScheme per endpoint? In Swagger UI I see the Authorize button show up, but the token isn't sent to any endpoints of mine currently :(

Comment: thanks! that worked for me. now how do I use it in the laravel controller end? I mean say I need to send the token only to logout the user.  how do I do that?

Comment: hi, sory, i m really new in this swagger stuff, where i put the secuirty scheme? is it in my annotation in controller?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case worked as follows:

In the src dir a following class (some general settings):

```
#[OA\Info(version: "0.1", title: "My First API")]
#[OA\Server(url: 'http://localhost:8080/api')]
#[OA\SecurityScheme(
    securityScheme: 'bearerAuth',
    type: 'http',
    in: 'header',
    scheme: 'bearer',
)]
class OpenApi
{
}
```

and endpoint:

```
#[OA\Get(
    path: '/someUrl',
    summary: 'some description',
    security: [['bearerAuth' => []]],
    tags: ['some tag'],
)
]
#[OA\Response(response: '200', description: 'The data 1')]
#[OA\Response(response: '401', description: 'Unauthorized')]
public function getSomeData($request, $response, $args)
```